# How to validate same name in inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to create a form where I have the same validation in several different tabs , but does not work

**The start date can not be greater than the end date**

I need to validate the fields in 3 different tabs in the same form. In the first validation works in the second tab does not work anymore.

The date format is: mm/yyyy

[Here is my Code - updated](https://jsfiddle.net/jrntpcmz/12/)

Here is my code:

```
function verifyDate(){
    var enterDate = $('.start-date').val(),
        exitDate = $('.end-date').val();

        var startDate = enterDate.substring(3, 7),
            leftDate = exitDate.substring(3, 7);

    if (startDate > leftDate) {
      $('.date-wrapper').addClass("has-error");
      $('.print-error').append('The start date can not be greater than the end date');
      allNextBtn.prop('disabled', true);
      $('.start-date').focus();
    } else {
      $('.date-wrapper').removeClass("has-error");
      allNextBtn.prop('disabled', false);
      $('.print-error').remove();
    }

};
```

Any help? Thanks a lot

Comment: Note you are using `>` on strings, I'm doubting that's what you are looking for. You will want to make them into `Date`s.

Comment: Hi @SpencerWieczorek The start date can not be greater than the end date

Comment: I know that, I've explained in my comment above why it's not working. Also `mm/yyyy` is not a valid date format, what about days?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I need to validate the fields in 3 different tabs in the same form. In the first validation works in the second tab does not work anymore. I don't need days

Comment: *"but does not work"* - What does that mean, *specifically*? What actually happens when you run the code? Do you get any errors in the console? If you've got multiple fields with the same `.start-date` and `.end-date` classes then that will be a problem because your function only checks the first of each.

Comment: @nnnnnn _If you've got multiple fields with the same .start-date and .end-date classes then that will be a problem because your function only checks the first of each._
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`verifyDate()` function isn't defined in that fiddle, because your JavaScript is set to execute onLoad.

Select "No wrap - in " to resolve the issue on the top left of the javascript section on fiddle.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnD6N.png)

Also  `allNextBtn.prop();` is not defined

**Update**

First, here you're taking YYYY from MM/YYYY, right?

```
var startDate = enterDate.substring(3, 7),
        leftDate = exitDate.substring(3, 7);
```

If you want to compare them as years you must parse these variable as Integers, so this.

```
if (startDate > leftDate)
```

Should be

```
if (parseInt(startDate, 10) > parseInt(leftDate, 10))
```

Tip: here you are checking just the year, you should extract the month and check it on another if nested inside the year check.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code. But I need each pair of independent validate inputs